# how to check which player disconnected in a game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

i'm making a multiplayer game with unity.
i'm using master server .player1(server) will be server and player2(client) will connect to player1.

now i need to understand which player disconnected?
 player1 can use `OnPlayerDisconnected(NetworkPlayer)` to check if player2 disconnected or not .but can't use [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.OnPlayerDisconnected.html) function in client side (only work in server side)

what player2 can do to understand player1 is disconnected or not ?

Answer (score 2):

`Network` broadcasts another message, `OnDisconnectedFromServer`. It is called on the client when it is disconnected from the server.

[Network.OnDisconnectedFromServer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.OnDisconnectedFromServer.html)

It is passed a `NetworkDisconnect` object that gives you information about the disconnect event, such as whether it was a lost connection or an intentional disconnect. The Unity Script Reference page has examples for that as well.

Comment: Why this event is not running on my server or client?

Comment: Have you actually used this? Searcing for "DisconnectedFromServer" in Unity Networking source code does not even return a result! (5.6 branch of https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/networking)

Comment: @GaziAlankus I have not used it in quite some time - note that this answer is from 2014. It's entirely possible that this has been deprecated. If this is true, and you find the correct way to do this, please add a new answer to this question :)

Comment: I can do neither at this time :) Unity docs has this function but it does not work, because it's not there in the code. At the moment I'm doing connection checks at every update...